# Data is coming in as a JSON object, how to parse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects, zapier

I'm trying to build a Zap that takes customer feedback via Unbird and sends a Slack messages that would make sense to anyone at my org who reads it.

Currently getting customer feedback data from Unbird into Zapier and it looks something like a javascript object, like this:

```
{
  0: website
  1: jon@email.com
  2: Jon
  3: Smith
  4: You guys have a great website, but should add dark mode.
}
```

And I want to send a message to Slack that says something like

`Jon Smith (jon@email.com) just sent you Website feedback: You guys have a great website, but should add dark mode.`

I can select and send the "entry property values" to Slack, it looks like this:

`website, jon@email.com, Jon, Smith, You guys have a great website, but should add dark mode.`

I tried using Zapier's Split function with a comma as the separator, but that doesn't successfully split it. I tried using a Zapier code snippet to isolate individual values, but when I do myobj.0 that doesn't work. Is this maybe an array? I don't think you can even have numbers for key names in js. It's been way too long since I did any coding.

I tried using JSON.stringify to make it a string, but in Zapier code snippets the output has to be an object, so I'm stuck with a stupid object again! I just want text, I could work with text, or some way to call individual values in the object for later use.

Help!

Comment: Assuming the json keys are always going to match the values of website, email, name.. Maybe you can use template literal to accomplish this: `const responseStr = ``${json[2] json[3]} (${json[1]}), just sent you ${json[0]} feedback: ${json[4]}`` `

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A I don't know how to split up an object into disparate pieces so that I can plug values into different parts of a sentence in a Zap to send to Slack.

Answer (score 1):

If the customer feedback is already coming in as an object where those keys are separated by a comma, you just need to return the output and this should split into individual entries for each value.

In your case -

```
var obj = {  0: "website", 1:"jon@email.com", 2: "Jon", 3: "Smith",4:"You guys have a great website, but should add dark mode"};output = [key:obj];
```